# How to have options on a dropdown menu sorted aplpabetically

Tags: reactjs

I have a dropdown menu that displays information in the order it was entered into the array however I would like it sorted alphabetically so that in the case that someone should search all objects in the array that start with the same letters will be grouped near each other there by giving the user an easier time finding the one that they are looking for with out having to look through the entire list. This is my code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import CallForm from './CallForm';
import { produce } from 'immer';

export default class EditPage extends React.Component {

    state = {
        call: {
            name: '',
            address: '',
            zip: '',
            neighborhood: '',
            landlord: '',
            appliance: '',
            brand: '',
            applianceLocation: '',
            type: '',
            workPreformed: '',
            additionalWorkAndNotes: '',
            calls: '',
            reasonForReturn: '',
            ammout: '',
            methodOfPayment: '',
            date: ''
        },
        calls: []
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        if (this.props.match.params.callId) {
            axios.get(`/api/calls/getbyid/${this.props.match.params.callId}`)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    this.setState({ call: data });
                });
        } else {
            axios.get('/api/calls/get').then(({ data }) => {
                this.setState({ calls: data });
            });
        }
    }

    onInputChange = e => {
        const nextState = produce(this.state, draft => {
            draft.call[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        });
        this.setState(nextState);
    }

    onSubmit = () => {
        axios.post('/api/calls/update', this.state.call).then(() => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        });
    }

    onSelectChange = e => {
        const id = e.target.value;
        axios.get(`/api/calls/getbyid/${id}`)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                this.setState({ call: data });
            });
    }

    render() {
        const  { name, address, zip, neighborhood, landlord, appliance, brand, applianceLocation, type, workPreformed, additionalWorkAndNotes, calls, reasonForReturn, ammout, methodOfPayment, date } = this.state.call;
        let content;
        if (name) {
            content = <CallForm
                name={name}
                address={address}
                zip={zip}
                neighborhood={neighborhood}
                landlord={landlord}
                appliance={appliance}
                brand={brand}
                applianceLocation={applianceLocation}
                type={type}
                workPreformed={workPreformed}
                additionalWorkAndNotes={additionalWorkAndNotes}
                calls={calls}
                reasonForReturn={reasonForReturn}
                ammout={ammout}
                methodOfPayment={methodOfPayment}
                date={date}

                onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
                onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            />
        }
        else {
            content = (
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 well">
                        <h3>Start typing to search by Name</h3>
                        <select className="form-control" onChange={this.onSelectChange}>

                            <option value="0" ><input type="text" />-- Search By Name--</option>


                            {this.state.calls.map(p => <option key={p.id}
                                value={p.id}>{p.name + ' ' + p.appliance}</option>)}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 well">
                            <h3>Start typing to search by Address</h3>
                            <select className="form-control" onChange={this.onSelectChange}>
                                <  option value="0" ><input type="text"/>-- Search By Address--</option>

                                {this.state.calls.map(p => <option key={p.id}
                                    value={p.id}>{p.address + ' ' + p.name}</option>)}
                            </select>
                        </div> 
                    </div>)
                </div>)


        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Edit call</h1>
               {content}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with this:

```
{
  this.state.calls
    .sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1))
    .map((p) => (
      <option key={p.id} value={p.id}>
        {p.name + ' ' + p.appliance}
      </option>
    ));
}
```

Comment: @mszp if it worked please mark the answer as correct :)